# Eclipse CDT(C++) gdb ignores breakpoints

Tags: debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Neon CDT IDE.
I have installed MinGW and insured that gdb is configured as the debugger.
When I set any breakpoints, they are all ignored.

No, the "ignore breakpoints" option is not enabled.

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Thanks,

-CAA14

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you Running the project instead of Debugging it?

Comment: @HighCommander4 No, I am debugging it.